# facebook comments using codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am trying to develop facebook comments application in my codeignitor project but i face problem like loading comment box and also not display all comment properly and when i use another fresh application codeignitor that works fine.

I use this code in view file

> (function(d, s, id){    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;    js = d.createElement(s); js.id =
>   id;    js.src =
>   "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789789652";
>   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);  } (document, 'script',
>   'facebook-jssdk'));

I use this code in controllers file

> class Fb_comments extends CI_Controller
>      {
>          function _*construct()
>
>           {
>         parent::*_construct();
>           }
>
> ```
>   function index()
>   {
> ```
>
> $this->load->view('fb_comments');
>         } 
>   }

any idea and advice will be appriciated

Thanks in advance..
bhavik patel

Comment: That code only loads the Facebook JavaScript SDK; you still need `<fb:comments>` boxes on the page to make them appear.

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking the code that actually displays the facebook comments block:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

where http://example.com is to be replaced by the site url you mentioned in the facebook code generator.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

When you press "get code" you have 2 codes to include in your view, the first the the JS SDK and the second is the div where you put the content.